# 'Which were a size too small.' or 'which size were too small.' Which one is correct?

Tags: word-order, relative-clauses

The whole sentence is

> Mr Boxell had deliberately sold the man a pair of shoes which were a size too small, knowing he would return them next day!

I'm so confused about *which were a size too small*, whether it is the correct order.

Comment: Note, by the way, that *a pair of X* is normally plural. See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31783 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22461 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7215.  However, not that it’s *Two pair doesn’t beat three of a kind*.

Comment: Try *which were too small by a (shoe) size*. If it's still not clear, you could try asking on English Language Learners; there's nothing unusual in the wording.

Comment: @tchrist .......can *had* be removed from the sentence??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Probably not, but without context, no one can say for sure.

Comment: @TimLymington Does 'by a size' mean by one step size?

Comment: I don't know what *one step size* means, so can't say. Shoes are sold in different sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is saying that the shoes were **one size too small** (e.g. were a size 10 instead of the size 11 that the customer required).

Your other example could also be used, but would have to be *whose size was too small*, but the wording in the original sentence is more correct.

Comment: What does 'whose' represent? Mr Boxell's a pair of shoes?

Comment: Whose represents the size belongs to the shoes, it's a weird little thing in English, in which a *whose* can also be used to describe the possession by a noun as well as a person. "Whose size was too small" indicates that the shoes possess a size that is too small. The first example I gave is much more common, and I would use it every time really.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of "which were a size too small" is correct in this sentence-

> Mr Boxell had deliberately sold the man a pair of shoes which were a
>   size too small, knowing he would return them next day!

"A" here indicates one size small.

If you take a look at this [lifestyle blog](http://samanthabusch.com/2013/01/how-to-make-too-small-shoes-fit-in-under-30-minutes/), there is a similar usage of "a size too small"-

> Ever go to the store and find a HOT pair of shoes on sale that are
>   just half a size too small?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing seems wrong with word order in 'Which were a size too small.'  Substitute the word "one" for "a" to get implied meaning.
 The second choice which could be written as "which were too small" is less specific. How many sizes too small?

Comment: To get what implied meaning?